# Limiting List Permissions Programmatically

Tags: 2007, list, development, list-definition, site

**Scenario:**

When a User (let say Controller 1) creates a site using a site definition, "which already has a Custom List definition in it and different other things(like lists, webparts)"

Custom List:
what it does is, You can create a item and assign it to any other controller or yourself.

**Question:**
So what I want is, When the Site is being created, I just want to give "add New Items" / Edit List Items permission for that specific list to Controller 1 or the Controller "n" he gave permission for that specific site.

I know I need to add code somewhere while creating the site, but dunno how I gonna do that in this context :/

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure which users should be allowed to do what, but if you need to give difference Controllers control of difference list items then you could look at [Setting item level security in an eventhandler](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2007/11/11/setting-item-level-security-in-an-eventhandler.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of code I wrote to change the permissions on a list. This isn't list items, but you can probably figure out how to do that part :)

```
    SPList splDocuments = spwWeb.Lists["Documents"];
    splDocuments.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
    string strGroup = "[The name of your group]";
    RemoveAllPermissions(splDocuments, strGroup);
```

And then these functions:

```
    private SPPrincipal GetPrincipal(SPSite spsSite, string strGroupName)
    {
        SPPrincipal sppGroup = null;

        if (SPUtility.IsLoginValid(spsSite, strGroupName))
        {
            sppGroup = spsSite.RootWeb.EnsureUser(strGroupName);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (SPGroup spgGroup in spsSite.RootWeb.SiteGroups)
            {
                if (spgGroup.Name.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ==
                    strGroupName.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    sppGroup = spgGroup;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return sppGroup;
    }

    private void RemoveAllPermissions(SPList splList, string strGroupName)
    {
        SPPrincipal sppPrincipal = GetPrincipal(splList.ParentWeb.Site, strGroupName);
        SPRoleAssignment spraRoleAssignment = splList.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(sppPrincipal);

        spraRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll();
        spraRoleAssignment.Update();

        splList.Update();
    }
```